# Confluence: Is there a way to surround text with a class of "tags" that I can call up from a page that lists all instances where the tag is used?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api, confluence-macros

Confluence holds the names of any custom classes that are created for any tasks where they are required. Each client has its own space.

Is there a way to surround the names of these classes with a set of custom "tags," so that I can call up the names of all custom classes (from all client pages across our confluence site) on a separate page? (think something like xml)

You can set up tables to use as templates (one template for many pages), but I am trying to set it up so that I can pull all information that is structured correctly (i.e., inside a set of these tags) onto a single page that can be monitored.